# Efficiently Counting Divisors of a Number in O(n^(1/3)) in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, coding-efficiency

I found an efficient algorithm to count divisors of a number in O(n^(1/3)) here: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/22317

I've implemented the algorithm in the code below. But it doesn't work properly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define endl "\n"
#define pi 2*acos(0)

#define debug(s) cout << #s << " = " << s << endl
#define all(v) (v).begin(), (v).end()
#define mem(a, val) memset(a, val, sizeof a)

vector<int> prime(10000000, 1); // array size is 10^7
void sieve(ll n){
    prime[0]=prime[1]=0;
    for(ll i=2; i<=sqrt(n); i++){
        if(prime[i]==1){
            for(ll j=2; i*j<=n; j++) prime[i*j]=0;
        }
    }
}
bool isPrime(ll n){
    if(n<2) return false;
    return prime[n];
}

vector<int> primeTable;
ll numberOfDivisors(ll n){
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
        if(prime[i]==1) primeTable.pb(i);
    }
    ll ans=1;
    for(int i=0; ; i++){
        if(primeTable[i]*primeTable[i]*primeTable[i]>n) break;
        ll cnt=1;
        while(n%primeTable[i]==0){
            n=n/primeTable[i];
            cnt++;
        }
        ans*=cnt;
    }
    double sqn=sqrt(n);
    if(isPrime(n)) ans*=2;
    else if((sqn-floor(sqn))==0 and isPrime((ll)sqn)) ans*=3;
    else if(n!=1) ans*=4;

    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    ll N=cbrt(n);
    sieve(N);
    cout << numberOfDivisors(n) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i.e for 15 it returns 2(should be 4), for 100 it returns 6(should be 9), for 999 it returns 8(which is correct), but again for 9999 it returns 6(should be 12). I think something is wrong in between line 42 and 45. But I'm unable to find the bug. Please help me find the bug.

Comment: Instead of just dumping the code here and hoping for the best, try and break the problem down into smaller chunks. Writing intricate mathematical code without unit tests is basically a fool's errand, so take the time to define some rigorous checks that can validate that this code is working correctly on a more modular level before integrating it. Each function should have one or more tests that verify it's working correctly for the expected range of inputs.

Comment: your defines dont make the code easier to read. Revoming them would be the first thing i would "fix"

Comment: Please don't do this: `#define ll long long` in code you're sharing. It makes the code harder to read. (The same goes for the other defines.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set initial value of `prime` is 1 here `vector<int> prime(10000000, 1)`. Then update the value of `prime` upto `n` in `seive(ll n)` function. So for `n+1` to `10000000` `prime` value will remain 1. In your main function, you ran the `sieve(N)` for `ll N=cbrt(n)`. For this reason your `isPrime(n)` is incorrect, because `n` could be greater than `N=cbrt(n)`. Fix that your code is good to go.

From the blog post, i understand that this algorithm is for finding factors of long long integer. They also mention that to check primality use Miller Rabin. The way you check `isPrime(n)` will not work for large integer.

Also update this part (change `1000000` to `cbrt(n)`):

```
ll numberOfDivisors(ll n){
    for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++){
        if(prime[i]==1) primeTable.pb(i);
    }
```